# Replaced rootViewController is still visible in background

Tags: ios, swift

When my App opens from background by user's response to notifications, I'll direct them to the respective screen depending on the notification. The process involved replacing the `window.rootViewController` in AppDelegate.

The following is my codes handling the notification:

```
if application.applicationState == .background {
    let info = userInfo["custom"] as! [AnyHashable : Any]
    let a = info["a"] as! [AnyHashable : Any]

    switch a["notificationType"] as! Int {
    case 1:
        let newVC = StoryBoardInstantiation.instantiateNewContentViewController(true)
        let leftVC = StoryBoardInstantiation.instantiateLeftPanelVC()
        let sideMenu = SSASideMenu(contentViewController: UINavigationController(rootViewController: newVC), leftMenuViewController: leftVC)

        self.window?.rootViewController = sideMenu
    }
}
```

Afterwards when the user navigates around the app, whenever there are animated changes to view controllers, the original ViewController(the one replaced in the codes) will be visible in the background.

How do I remove the previous rootViewController that is already replaced?

Comment: where is justListedVC?

Comment: @SourLeangChhean typo it is suppose to be newVC

Comment: @BenOng try again after adding self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible() this line just below self.window?.rootViewController = sideMenu

Comment: @Aakash Thanks, it works!